# VBA - multiple Worksheet Changes

Tags: excel, vba

How do I do this change for 3 pairs of separate cells.  I know this 1st code works for 1 pair of cells by putting it on two diff worksheets

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim p1 As Range, p2 As Range
    Set p1 = Range("L268")
    Set p2 = Sheets("Calculator").Range("J2")
    If Intersect(Target, p1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        p2.Value = p1.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

and then this on the other

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim p1 As Range, p2 As Range
    Set p1 = Range("J2")
    Set p2 = Sheets("Proposal Summary").Range("L268")
    If Intersect(Target, p1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        p2.Value = p1.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub`
```

but how do I add in two other pairs of cells I also want to equal each other?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim p1 As Range, p2 As Range
    Dim a1 As Range, a2 As Range
    Dim h1 As Range, h2 As Range

    Set p1 = Range("J2")
    Set p2 = Sheets("Proposal Summary").Range("L268")
    Set a1 = Range("J3")
    Set a2 = Sheets("Proposal Summary").Range("L271")
    Set h1 = Range("J4")
    Set h2 = Sheets("Proposal Summary").Range("L274")

    If Intersect(Target, p1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        p2.Value = p1.Value

    If Intersect(Target, a1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        a2.Value = a1.Value

    If Intersect(Target, h1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        h2.Value = h1.Value

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: What part of this code is not working as intended?

Comment: My attempt at combining all 3 (last bit of code there) does nothing so I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Get rid of all the `Exit Sub`s, change the second two `If` statements to `ElseIf` and add an `End If`

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: Purpose is having 3 different cells on Calculator worksheet and exact the same 3 cells on Proposal Summary worksheet and no matter which worksheet I use to change the value, I want the other to update with the changed value.  I figured it out for 1 pair, but struggling doing it for all 3 pairs.

Answer (score 0):

If I've read the ranges involved correctly you should be able to combine the whole thing like this.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J2:J4")) Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Proposal Summary").Range("L268").Offset((Target.Row - 2) * 3).Value = Target.Value
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

If you want this to work the other way, i.e. update the other sheet when a value changes on `Proposal Summary` you could use this.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L268, L271, L274")) Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Calculator").Range("J2").Offset((Target.Row - 268) / 3).Value = Target.Value
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - almost there I think.  If that goes on the Calculator worksheet, what would go on the Proposal Summary worksheet so that if a value is changed at either location the cell on the other sheet would also update.

Comment: I've added that to my answer.

Comment: I'll try and make this easier by moving cells.  On the Calculator worksheet J2:J4.  On the Proposal Summary worksheet, M267:M269.  Does that help so we don't have to offset?

Comment: You would still need to offset with those ranges but it would be simpler.